# ChunkerTransformStream, a transform stream to take arbitrary chunk sizes and make them consistent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code to interface with a wire protocol that requires data to be inserted into a stream at regular byte intervals.  Every 8KB (or at some other definable interval), a small chunk will be inserted.  To make this easy, I decided to create a transform stream that would take a flowing stream and write fixed chunk sizes.  That is, this stream can be written to in any size (2KB here, 500KB there, 5 bytes next, etc.) and it will output chunks in 8KB of size every time.

```
var stream = require('stream');
function ChunkerTransformStream (chunkSize) {
    chunkSize = chunkSize || 8192;

    var buffer = new Buffer(0);

    var chunker = new stream.Transform({objectMode: true});
    chunker._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk]);

        while (buffer.length >= chunkSize) {
            this.push(buffer.slice(0, chunkSize));
            buffer = buffer.slice(chunkSize);
        }

        done();
    }

    chunker._flush = function (done) {
        if (buffer.length) {
            this.push(buffer);
            done();
        }
    }

    return chunker;
}

module.exports = ChunkerTransformStream;
```

This transform stream will be used heavily in my code, having several megabit pushed through it per second.  Is this the most efficient way to achieve what I want?  I am most concerned about my buffer operations.  It's my understanding that `Buffer.concat()` is very expensive, as it allocates an entirely new buffer and copies the first two to it.

Any feedback, on performance or otherwise, is welcomed.

Comment: Is there a version of this which works with StreamTransform in the browser? I tried to create one but could not find any documentation or examples for the same.

Comment: I ended up creating one that works in the browser. https://gist.github.com/samaybhavsar/97d2674536c6f64de8b6d2c43085a347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this without using `Buffer.concat()` and by only allocating a single `Buffer` of size `chunkSize`.

The basic flow for each chunk coming in to the stream is:

1. If we have data in `buffer` already and there's enough data in the incoming `chunk` to fill `buffer` up to `chunkSize`, copy the appropriate bytes from `chunk` to `buffer`, push `buffer`, and then clear it.
2. If we have data in `buffer` already but there **isn't** enough data in the incoming `chunk` to fill `buffer` up to `chunkSize`, append `chunk` to `buffer`.
3. If there's nothing in `buffer`, push `chunkSize` chunks from `chunk` (that's a mouth full) and put and remaining bytes in `buffer`.

This greatly reduces the number of byte that are copied around. Instead of each `chunk` being copied to `buffer`, only the bytes that are needed from `chunk` are copied. And, if `chunk` happens to exactly fit in `chunkSize`, no bytes are copied at all.

I tried this out using your code as a base. I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it works well as a proof as concept:

```
var stream = require('stream');

// Helper function to push chunks of chunkSize from buffer to stream
// returns a Buffer containing the remaining bytes that weren't pushed
function pushChunks(buffer, stream, chunkSize) {
    var offset = 0,
        size = buffer.length;

    while (size >= chunkSize) {
        stream.push(buffer.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize));
        offset += chunkSize;
        size -= chunkSize;
    }

    return buffer.slice(offset, offset + size);
}

function ChunkerTransformStream (chunkSize) {
    chunkSize = chunkSize || 8192;

    var buffer = new Buffer(chunkSize),
        bufferOffset = 0;

    var chunker = new stream.Transform({objectMode: true});

    chunker._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
        // If we have data in the buffer, try to fill it up to chunkSize.
        if (bufferOffset != 0) {
            var bytesNeeded = (chunkSize - bufferOffset);
            // If we have enough bytes in this chunk to get buffer up to chunkSize,
            // fill in buffer, push it, and reset its offset.
            // Otherwise, just copy the entire chunk in to buffer.
            if (chunk.length >= bytesNeeded) {
                chunk.copy(buffer, bufferOffset, 0, bytesNeeded);
                this.push(buffer);
                bufferOffset = 0;
                chunk = chunk.slice(0, chunk.length - bytesNeeded);
            } else {
                chunk.copy(buffer, bufferOffset);
                bufferOffset += chunk.length;
            }
        }

        // If there's nothing in the buffer, push the chunk.
        if (bufferOffset == 0) {
            var remainingChunk = pushChunks(chunk, this, chunkSize);
            // If there are bytes left over, put them in the buffer.
            if (remainingChunk.length) {
                remainingChunk.copy(buffer, bufferOffset);
                bufferOffset += remainingChunk.length;
            }
        }

        done();
    }

    chunker._flush = function (done) {
        if (bufferOffset) {
            this.push(buffer.slice(0, bufferOffset));
            done();
        }
    }

    return chunker;
}

module.exports = ChunkerTransformStream;
```

Comment: Firstly, chunk = chunk.slice(0, chunk.length - bytesNeeded) is wrong, it should be
chunk = chunk.slice(bytesNeeded, chunk.length) instead. Secondly, we need to make a copy of the buffer before we push it. otherwise we can end up with mixed data

Answer (score 6):

**First of all, your code looks great.** It brought me to study the internal workings of Node's stream API.

The piece that you're concerned with, and rightfully so, is:

```
buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk]);
```

That's *the* way to do it. There are no other ways to do what you want to do without using [bufferjs](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-bufferjs), which likely handles things the same way, or less efficiently.

Now, there is one optimization you can make here. By adding the `totalLength` parameter of Buffer.concat `Buffer.concat(list, [totalLength])` you can improve efficiency by avoiding an additional loop in the function, which would need to check the new length of the new buffer.

```
    Name         Description                                       Required?    Type
    list         List of Buffer objects to concat                  Required     array
    totalLength  Total length of the buffers when concatenated.    Optional     number
```

> If totalLength is not provided, it is read from the buffers in the
>   list. However, this adds an additional loop to the function, so it is
>   faster to provide the length explicitly. - See more at:
>   http://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-buffer.php#sthash.qISHPlCO.dpuf

Not sure if this will help or not, but other than that, I don't see any possible optimizations.

Comment: I'm glad that after you've helped me with node.js multiple times on Stack Overflow, I can try to give back. It's interesting that I was struggling with just learning Node a few months ago, and thanks to people like you, I can now study and write code at this level.

Comment: +1, thanks for the feedback and I'm happy that I've been able to help you with questions in the past!

Comment: Looks like I was wrong!

Answer (score 3):

The `_flush` function is wrong.  It will never close the stream if the buffer is empty.

```
chunker._flush = function (done) {
    if (buffer.length) {
        this.push(buffer);
    }
    done();
}
```